# Marketing Cloud Manage Data Retention

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have a question about data retention policy.
If I create a data retention policy to my data extensio, the retention policy will only delete records older than 90 days.
The policy will only delete records older than 90 days or all records from my data extension

Comment: also outlined here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_manage_de_policies.htm&type=5

Answer (score 3):

It's up to you to choose.

You can choose to delete **All records**

Or this retention time to be for **each record** (Individual records)

Or even to delete the **data extension itself** (All records and data extensions).

You choose this at creation time, but you can also edit this Retention policy later

[image]

Comment: So, for Leandro's question... for this Data Extension, will the "Individual Records" option ONLY delete specific rows older than 6 days?